# Convert docx to pdf fails in vbscript

Tags: pdf, vbscript, docx

I want to convert a docx file to pdf with vbscript. But my script always gives errors.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
Set oFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For i= 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count -1
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   objWord.Visible = False

   oFile = WScript.Arguments(i)
   dirPath = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(oFile)

       If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "DOC" Or UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "DOCX" Then
          pdfPath = dirPath & "\" & GetFilenameWithoutExtension(oFile) & ".pdf"
          Set objDoc = objWord.documents.open(dirPath & "\" & oFile)
          objDoc.saveas pdfPath, 17
          objDoc.Close

       End If   

   objWord.Quit   

Next

Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(ByVal FileName)
  Dim Result, i
  Result = FileName
  i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If ( i > 0 ) Then
    Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
  End If
  GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
```

This code gives the following error:

> script.vbs(15, 5) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required:
>   'objWord.documents.open(...)'

I have tried the following:

```
Set oFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For i= 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count -1
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   objWord.Visible = False

   Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(i))
   dirPath = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.Arguments(i))

       If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "DOC" Or UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "DOCX" Then
          pdfPath = dirPath & "\" & GetFilenameWithoutExtension(oFile.Name) & ".pdf"
          Set objDoc = objWord.documents.open(dirPath & "\" & oFile.Name)
          objDoc.saveas pdfPath, 17
          objDoc.Close

       End If   

   objWord.Quit   

Next

Function GetFilenameWithoutExtension(ByVal FileName)
  Dim Result, i
  Result = FileName
  i = InStrRev(FileName, ".")
  If ( i > 0 ) Then
    Result = Mid(FileName, 1, i - 1)
  End If
  GetFilenameWithoutExtension = Result
End Function
```

But then I get the error:

> script.vbs(12, 5) Microsoft Word: Command failed

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The second version works on a document created in word.

Because I use this on a document created by code this option doesn't work in word itself.
So it is normal it won't work with the script also.